# set file permissions with servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-permissions

I am using Apache Commons File Upload to write a short jsp program that allows students to upload files to our server.  The server is a Linode running Ubuntu Precise Pangolin.  Please forgive my lack of knowledge about server administration.

So far, I am successful in uploading the file only if the target folder has rights set to 777 (rwx for all).  This feels insecure to me, so I was hoping that I could put the folder at 755 and then momentarily change it to writable (in code) as the jsp script runs, and change it back immediately after the uploaded file has been saved (also in code).

I know that class File in Java has a setWritable method and I attempted to use that.  However, that method won't work unless the user has rights to change the file permissions on the operating system.  Thus, an exception is thrown as permission is denied by the operating system. This led me to ask:

**When a servlet runs, who is the user?  Whose rights are being checked by the operating system?**

I am the owner of the jsp file that contains the file upload script, so I would have thought that I was the user as the script runs.  I have rights to change file permissions.  Yet the servlet does not.  Hence my confusion.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Be extremely careful with this.  Make sure that the folder is not under the "web root" - you don't want your students to be able to upload some nasty script then get your server to run it.

Comment: @DavidWallace-- Hi David-- can you help me understand what rights the servlet has?  How are those determined?  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidWallace-- I agree about being careful.  That is why I didn't set the file permissions to 777.  There are only five students and I will have a record in the database with each upload.  The idea is for them to learn how to do web programming, so I need for them to be able to upload to the server.

Comment: Generally, whoever installed the web server software or application server software will have created a user for anonymous web requests to run as.  You could have a special directory that the anonymous web user can write to, or you could create actual logins for each student and force them to log in, in which case anything each of them runs will run as that user.  But you should discuss this with your hosting provider - there are almost certainly limits on what they will let you do.

Answer (score 2):

When a servlet runs, the user from an operating system perspective is the user that the Servlet Container (Jetty, Tomcat, Glassfish, etc) is running as. It is the rights of that user that are being checked by the operating system. The owner of the JSP file is irrelevant. Well, to be precise the JSP file has to be readable by the user that the Servlet Container is running as otherwise it can't be executed but in terms of OS permissions for the actions defined by that JSP, the only thing that matters is the user the Servlet Container is running as.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that is very helpful.  I should have mentioned that we are running the servlets with Tomcat.  To figure out who the user is, should I look in the Tomcat user's file?  Or is there some way for me to ask programmatically "who is the user"?